# Git Fatal Repo Not Found - Credential Storing

Tags: git, github

Getting Error message after storing git credentials. Not 100% sure why.

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository '<<URL>>' not found
```

I have stored the credentials using:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Basically they are credentials of another account for a specific repository.

When I use these credentials to pull, and using the same url, it works perfectly finding and clones and pulls and even pushes, but just when they are saved in the credential helper, it doesn't work.

Comment: git config --global credential.helper wincred 

try to use this command and check it works ?

Comment: Are you using different git clients? E.g. `git` command line and `Git Extensions`? They have different behaviour when accepting credentials.

Comment: @MukeshRam that seemed to work perfectly. Do you want to make that an answer? Also why  did that work rather than the command `store`